# Load a vim buffer into a ruby variable

Tags: ruby, vim

I'm looking for a way to retrieve what has been entered in vim and load it in a ruby variable.

User type:

```
myProgram -m
```

Then Vim appears. Whenever the user quit Vim, "myProgram" retrieves the user's input.

I tried doing something (naive)

```
message = `vim`
```

However, I get "Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal"

Thank you very much

Comment: executing via backticks starts a subshell without a controlling terminal, which VIM requires for doing its textbased gui stuff. However, to get thigns between vim and ruby, you can have ruby write out to a temporary file, point vim at that, then slurp the file back in after vim exits.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm gonna do that.

Comment: I'm actually still stucked... Even if I specify a file to Vim in my program (using the backticks), it stills going to start in a subshell. Is there a way to start vim in the current user shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When inside vim, you can run `:%!your_program` and your_program will be invoked with the current buffer as it's stdin.

Comment: I'm actually looking for a way to grab vim's buffer content when the user quit it with `:wq`, given he used `myProgram -m` to start vim of course.

Comment: You'd then create a temporary file, pass it as an argument to `vim` and block until vim exits, then check the mtime or content of the file you created. I believe this is what source control software such as SVN and git do for commit messages.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'm doing right now. I just found out the `system` method on Kernel to invoke script in the current shell.

Answer (score 1):

You should just need to write out your data so far to a temporary filename, then run something like `system(ENV["EDITOR"], tmpfile)`, then read `tmpfile` back in.  I suggest using the EDITOR or VISUAL environment variables, people set those to preferred editors for programs to use (ie if someone prefers Emacs and can't even exit Vim, they won't get confused).

Answer (score 1):

If you can work with gVim or MacVim, you can use the `-f` flag:

```
-f or --nofork    Foreground: Don't fork when starting GUI
```

which will make your Ruby code pause while the app (either gvim or MacVim) is running.

Grabbing the content of the editor is a bit more complex, but easily handled by your code pre-creating a temp file as a stub, and passing that to Vim when its launched. Edit away, save the buffer, then quit the editor. When control returns to Ruby open the file again and read its contents into a variable.

You'll notice that happening on Linux if you set your environment `EDITOR` variable to vim, and edit a command-line or tell SVN to use it for its `svn diff` command.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at how the "visudo", "vipw"... commands manage it (on linux).